# How to do I hide title in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-online, title

Hope you're well;

I wanted to know what is best way to hide title page in SharePoint 2016.

[image]

if remove it from title setting it will affect site navgation top link .

what is best way to do it?

Comment: You can directly add a content editor web part in the page and add css to hide the title.

Answer (score 4):

In a separate CSS file, loaded after corev15.css, add the following

```
h1, .ms-h1 {
    display: none;
}
```

[image: Sample]

Comment: You shouldn't, since updates from Microsoft would overwrite those changes. Instead create a new CSS-file, upload it to the Style Library and reference it from your copy of the Seattle or Oslo master page.